# How to add a NSTextField to a window in the window's init via a method

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

I want to programatically add several NSTextFields to a window when it loads.  I call the below method for each one in the init such as:

```
- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window{
    [self addTextField:firstTextField toWindow:window at:20];
}

-(void)addTextField:(NSTextField*)theTextField toWindow:(NSWindow*)theWindow at:(CGFloat)y{

    theTextField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, y, 200, 20)];
    [theTextField setBezeled:NO];
    [theTextField setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [theTextField setEditable:NO];
    [theTextField setSelectable:YES];

    [[theWindow contentView] addSubview:theTextField];
}
```

I don't get any errors, not even when I call the setStringValue for one of the NSTextFields.  However, they are not visible in the window.  Have I missed something simple, or am I trying something that is not allowed?

Thanks

Comment: How you set the setstringvalue? can you show a sample? maybe is this the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:-

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
  NSRect frameRect = NSMakeRect(10, 20, 200, 20);
  NSTextField *theTextField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:frameRect];
  [theTextField setBezeled:YES];
  [theTextField setDrawsBackground:NO];
  [theTextField setEditable:NO];
  [theTextField setSelectable:YES];
  [vw addSubview:theTextField]; 
  [[[self window]contentView]addSubview:vw];
  [super windowDidLoad];

  // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's   window has been loaded from its nib file.
}
```

Comment: Yes, that of course works.  But I want to insert several NSTextFields with the same characteristics and thought it might be nice to make the code compact instead of  writing [txt1 setSelectable:YES]; [txt2 setSelectable:YES]; ...

Answer (score 0):

If you load your window from xib you shouldn't override `-initWithWindow:`, use `-windowDidLoad` instead and add your textfields in this method. But if you create your window programmatically your `-initWithWindow:` must look like this:

```
-(id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow*)window {
    self = [super initWithWindow:window];
    if(self) {
        [self addTextField:firstTextField toWindow:self.window at:20];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I in fact have code that looks just like that.  I should have cut and pasted.  As I said, it does not yield any errors -- neither at compilation nor execution -- but does not show my NSTextField, either...